# SDL 2 C Compiler Flags

Tags: c, linux, gcc, sdl

Whenever I run the following, I get undefined references to all the SDL-related functions used in my program:

```
cc -lSDL2 -lGL *.o
```

I believe this is caused by the lack of `-l` linker flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To link to SDL and OpenGL:

```bash
cc *.o -lSDL2 -lGL ...
```

For Linux systems, you should use [`pkg-config`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config):

```bash
cc -c main.c $(pkg-config sdl2 --cflags)
cc main.o $(pkg-config sdl2 --libs)
```

(Make sure linker arguments like `-l` go after your source files)

Comment: It worked! Thanks, and wish me luck on my further SDL adventures...